# Can a physical load balancer offer failover as well?

Tags: load-balancing, failover, f5

Can a physical load balancer offer failover as well? My worry is what if the load balancer itself fails? How to provide redundancy in such cases??

Answer (score 0):

yes, most load balancers offer high availability in active/standby, some offer active/active, or active clusters. For physical devices in proximity, hardware failover is an option, but for virtual load balancers and physical load balancers too far apart will use network heartbeats.